# Use Google Maps in an Android Application and Zoom Level

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have created two sample Android Applications in order to find the best way to integrate Google Maps with my application.

I found out that using WebView and Google Maps Javascript API v3 the Zoom Level is much greater than using Android Mapview.

I am doing something wrong? Can I have the same Zoom Level I achieved with Javascript APIv3 using MapView or how can I increase the zoom level in my MapView version of the application?

Is there a reason why Google allows a greater Zoom Level to Javascript API v3 than in a MapView?

**MapView**

[image: MapView]

**WebView with JavaScript API v3**

[image]

Comment: Android does not use the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Comment: That's strange ... I get the same zoom levels with Android `MapView` as I get using the google maps in my computer browser. I just see a bigger image in the computer because the screen is bigger. Aren't you somehow limiting the zoom level in `MapView`?

Comment: @Marcelo you can use it through a WebView. Please check the attached screenshots!

Comment: It's either a web application (Google Maps API, Javascript) or an Android application, (Java), but not both.

Comment: @Marcelo, ofcourse but the question is why a Web Application provides greater zoom than a Java Application.

Comment: I see your point, but still your question is about Android Mapview and not about the Javascript API V3. (Feel free to rollback the tag removal, if you prefer ).

Comment: @Marcelo no problem. Just take a look at the pictures and please let me know if you have any suggestions

Comment: I don't know much about Android apps, but just out of curiosity, what value(s) do you get if you do map.getZoom() at maximum zoom in either application? Is it the same number? and What about on the satellite map type? Same zoom number or different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Background**

`Google Maps Javascript API v3` and `MapView` are both tile based maps. These tiles are pre-rendered for different zoom levels and limit the minimum and maximum zoom you can get for the map.

**Why diiferent zooms**

Middle 2012, Google released `Google Maps Javascript API v3` (making previous version deprecated) which is based on a new set of tiles. This new set of tiles includes pre-rendered tiles for higher zoom levels then previous version.

Unfortunately, `MapView` has not received any update for a long time and still uses the old tiles version, with smaller maximum zoom levels.

**Note**

`Google Maps` application for Android (that can be download from Google Play) is already using the new tile version and can achieve higher zoom levels than `MapView`, but no equivalent API has been made available for Android.

Regards.

Comment: I've just found that Google released a new version of MapView for Android `Google Maps Android API v2`. Link here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score 3):

You can set zoomlevel as follows

```
 mapController = locationMap.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(17);
```

where locationMap is object of MapView